# Number format exception in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am getting number format exception while trying to get the issue details by using id.

```
RemoteIssue ri = jira.getIssueById(JIRAtoken, string.Format(IssueKey));
```

here `jiratoken` is string. But giving exception. Any one have any idea?

Comment: Could you give more detail? `jira` in instance of what? RemoteIssue from which package?

Comment: The id of an issue looks like 12345 (not TEST-1) and is constant.
The issue key looks like TEST-1 and can change over time

Comment: You're probably wanting to use getIssue not getIssueById

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using the SOAP Web Service API of JIRA (4).

I solved it by using **`getIssue`** instead of `getIssueById`. With `getIssue`, JIRA expects the key like MYPROJECT-3.

Now I send a request like this, and it works :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:getIssue soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="xsd:string">MyAuthToken</in0>
         <in1 xsi:type="xsd:string">MYPROJECT-1</in1>
      </soap:getIssue>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```